# Javascript redirection based on url subdomain

Tags: javascript, redirect

I'm going to write a script placed in the root of my server that will redirect users to the correct page based on the url subdomain, the pages to be reach are on another server but on the same ip, all the server had an httpd service in different port (eg. s1.example.com goes to 11.11.11.11:801) - That's cause are vmware esxi machine, and can't find another easy method to link my domain.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
if (window.location.hostname == "s1.example.com") {
        window.location.replace("11.22.33.44:801");
} else if (window.location.hostname == "s2.example.com") {
        window.location.replace("11.22.33.44:802");
} else {
    document.write("<center>Sorry, incorrect server id</center>");
}
</script>
<body>
<center>Server Redirection in progress...</center>
</body>
```

This redirect to `about:blank` and don't work.

Can someone help? Thanks in advice.

Comment: This strikes me as odd, typically this sort of resolution happens on the server side.

Comment: Seems to me you should be using some sort of proxy... this is not a good way to approach this at all.

Comment: Sorry but i'm not very good at setting up proxies or a dns server, and i can't find another solution.

Comment: @andreaem  It's quite simple there are plenty of examples using nginx, nodejs, apache, haproxy.. the list goes on.  I highly suggest taking the time and doing this correctly.

Comment: @NickDelaney you're probably right, i'm trying to do this js for now and later must to read something about what you say, have you got a link where i can read a tutorial?

Comment: @andreaem http://serverfault.com/questions/293205/haproxy-domain-routing ...also https://seanmcgary.com/posts/haproxy---route-by-domain-name

Comment: Please consider the advice of the other comments, but it seems the reason your code doesn't work is because window.location.replace requires a scheme to work. So you could do window.location.replace("//11.22.33.44:801") to keep the existing scheme or specify one.